# Generating an HMAC-SHA256 key within function doesn't work but generating in IRB does

Tags: ruby, base64, signature, hmac, servicebus

tl;dr

A function that generates the **$sb_token** global variable (which is a HMAC-SHA256 key) doesn't seem to generate it correctly/accurately, whereas if I manually run the steps in the function, it does.

---

I'm debugging my Ruby script in IRB, and encountering a strange problem.

Maybe you're going to tell me I'm using variables all wrong, and I'm happy to be schooled, but I can't understand what is going on here.

I have this function that generates the **$sb_token** variable (I don't exactly understand all the usage of OpenSSL / Base64 / hmac stuff, but I have proven this works):

```
def get_service_bus_token()
    
    resourceUri = $resourceUri
    sasKeyName = $sasKeyName
    sasKey = $sasKey
    
    # url encoded
    encoded = ERB::Util.url_encode(resourceUri)
    
    # ttl
    timeNow = Time.now; $sb_token_timestamp = timeNow
    now = timeNow.to_i 
    minute = 60
    ttl = ((now ) + minute).to_s;
    #ttl = 1646428676.to_s
    
    # sig
    signature = encoded + '
    ' + ttl
        digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
        hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(digest, sasKey, signature)
        #hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, sasKey, signature)
        
        hash = Base64.strict_encode64(hmac)

    $sb_token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + encoded + "&sig=" + ERB::Util.url_encode(hash) + "&se=" + ttl + "&skn=" + sasKeyName;
    return $sb_token

end
```

When I execute the above *get_service_bus_token()* function, the **$sb_token** object is created and stored as a global variable.

I use the **$sb_token** object in another function as an Authorization header:

`headers['Authorization'] = $sb_token`

And then make a request with this header:

`response = HTTParty.post(url, :headers=>headers, :body=>body )`

This does not work - I receive an Invalid authorization token response:

`#<Net::HTTPUnauthorized 401 SubCode=40103: Invalid authorization token signature readbody=true>`

However, here's the confusing part.

If I manually run the steps within the *get_service_bus_token()* function (i.e. copy & paste them into IRB) and therefore creating the **$sb_token** object like this:

`$sb_token = "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + encoded + "&sig=" + ERB::Util.url_encode(hash) + "&se=" + ttl + "&skn=" + sasKeyName;`

Then when I execute these steps, it works!!!

`headers['Authorization'] = $sb_token`
   `response = HTTParty.post(url, :headers=>headers, :body=>body )`

`#<Net::HTTPCreated 201 Created readbody=true>`

This confuses me so much.

In essence, a function that generates the **$sb_token** global variable doesn't seem to generate it correctly/accurately, whereas if I manually run the steps in the function, it does.

This strikes me as a problem with either a) the usage of global variables or b) the creation of the strings generated inside the function vs on the IRB prompt is different.

Anyone got any insight or clues here?

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding how the rest of your application is constructed it's difficult to say for certain. However I can advise you that using global variables is bad practice that can lead to a variety of issues very similar to the ones you're describing here. You can read about [ruby global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ruby+global+variable) issues here and elsewhere.

Global variables are shared across all threads in a multi-threaded application. If you have two threads running concurrently that set the values of global variables then you will have a race condition. For example, you're setting `$sb_token` at the end of this method; if two threads call this method simultaneously then this global value will be overwritten by the last one to run. Ruby thread scheduling may mean that it executes in this order:

1. First thread invokes method setting `$sb_token` to value A
2. Second thread invokes method setting `$sb_token` to value B
3. Second thread runs subsequent method using `$sb_token` with value B
4. First thread runs subsequent method using `$sb_token` with value B (not A)

Likewise, the variables that you're *using* at the beginning of the method are likely being set somewhere else in your application and they are subject to the same kind of issue.

The reason that you don't see those errors in IRB is because IRB is single-threaded and there are no possible concurrency issues when there's only a single thread.

I can't give you direct advice about how to construct your application without global variables because I don't know what the rest of it looks like, for example if you're using classes and class instances. But generally you should look at [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29) for guidance. You likely either want to encapsulate your variables by using them as arguments to methods, like this:

```rb
def get_service_bus_token(resourceUri, sasKeyName, sasKey)
  ...
end
```

Or by setting them as instance variables:

```rb
def initialize
  @resouceUri = ...
  ...
end

def get_service_bus_token
  ...
  encoded = ERB::Util.url_encode(@resourceUri)
  ...
end
```

But [you should as a best practice avoid global variables](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#instance-vars) and [class variables](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-class-vars) in almost all circumstances unless you have a clear understanding of how they work and why you need to use them.

Lastly, I suggest that you read the linked Ruby Style Guide. There are some tips in there that you should consider following to make your code more idiomatic, for example:

1. [Snake Case for Symbols, Methods and Variables](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars)
2. [Should I Terminate Expressions with `;`?](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-semicolon)
3. [Indentation](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#spaces-indentation)